# Angular 4 App: Objects shrunken on screen

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I am working on an Angular 4 application. While navigating through the various screens and entering data, I tried to cut the data in the name field so as to paste it in other fields to save time.

My fingers slipped on the keyboard and I inadvertently pressed a combination of keys (Ctrl-something) that completely shrunk all the objects on the screen. It is not a code problem because the code was compiled and working just fine. The images are of normal sizes but all of the texts and input fields are shrunken to near invisible.

Would anyone know what this is?

Comment: Are you in Windows?

Comment: on Mac I would do CMD+ to zoom and CMD- to shrink. Maybe in Windows it should be CTRL+ and CTRL- ?

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. That worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows running machine do `CTRL+` to zoom and `CTRL-` to shrink. On a Mac do `CMD+` and `CMD-`.

Comment: @koque, If this answered your question, would you accept it as well?